# How to update class in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change class(inside directive) on click of directive,
Here is my current code where `scope.myattr` is updating in console but not in template or view:

```
<test order="A">Test</test>

.directive("test", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myattr: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myattr = attrs.myattr;
      element.bind('click', function () {
        console.log(scope.myattr);
        if (scope.myattr == 'A') {
          scope.myattr = 'B';
        }
        else {
          scope.myattr = 'A';
        }
      });
    },
    template: `
          <span ng-transclude></span>
          <span class="sortIcon {{myattr}}">{{myattr}}</span>`
  }
});
```

Comment: You probably need to call `$apply` method to force the digest cycle of the parent scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is regarding to digest cycle execution using `$apply` method.

Replace this line: `scope.myattr = attrs.myattr;`

**by this:**

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.myattr = attrs.myattr;
});
```

This manually forces a digest cycle to happen on the scope, which will run through all of its watchers and look for changes.

Remember doing that with all the updates over that scope.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks Eleazar, It works! But if I try without attribute `<test>Test</test>` it gives an error "Expression 'undefined' in attribute..", can I use this attribute as optional?

Comment: Change this `myattr: "="` by this `myattr: "=?"`.  The question mark makes the attribute optional

Comment: I have one more query on the same, I'm using this directive at 5 places on same page, I want to add these classes on the last clicked directive and want to remove these classes from rest of the 4 directives.

Comment: Here is a similar example of jQuery code: `$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});`

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work with add class and remove class. Extra benefit is you are not "polluting" HTML with brackets, everything is in controller

Test

```
.directive("test", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myattr: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myattr = attrs.myattr;
        elem.bind('click', function (e) {
            if (scope.myattr == 'A') {
               angular.element(e.target).removeClass('A');
               angular.element(e.target).addClass('B');
            }
            if (scope.myattr == 'B') {
               angular.element(e.target).removeClass('B');
               angular.element(e.target).addClass('A');
            }

        });
      });
    },
    template: `
          <span ng-transclude></span>
          <span class="sortIcon">{{myattr}}</span>`
  }
});
```

If you wanna pollute HTML with code then opt for `ng-class` directive. It's meant to be used for class expressions and provides more options then direct binding of class name.

Comment: Thanks DanteTheSmith

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against using $apply because you will run into a lot of problems when you force a digest cycle. Specifically, you can't interrupt and start a new digest cycle, if one is running currently. Angular will throw an error in this case. Explicit digest cycles also impact performance negatively as it has to run a loop to check all the scope variables to see what has changed. I would suggest using "ng-class" for expression based classes.

You need to run a digest cycle manually only if you have changed a scope variable outside the context of Angular, like specified in the article below.

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

And I think your current solution of forced digest cycle only works because of your two-way data binding, because it is not in the scope of your directive because of the way you specified ng-transclude. It is better to have proper scope structure and not force any digest cycle, because directives have their own digest cycles.

Comment: Thanks Sujit, I will try it!